# ssh change user and execute command

Tags: bash, ssh

This is my command that I have in my script:

```
ssh -i $KEY $USER@$HOST "sudo su tom; echo $DATA >> /home/user/file.txt
```

These commands work fine on there own but together in the script it just hangs.

If you run this command by itself `sudo su tom; cat /home/user/file.txt`
It will only execute cat when you logout of the user tom.

How do you change user and execute a command in a bash script ?

Comment: Have you configured the `sudoers` file to permit password-less logins for whatever login you're using? (i.e. does there exist the chance that a password prompt is blocking the rest of the commands from proceeding?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to switch users, executing as root seemed to do the trick.

`ssh -i $KEY $USER@$HOST "echo "$DATA" |sudo tee $DIRECTORY"`

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what Paul Calabro suggested, which I don't think is your main problem , you should define what command-line interpreter(shell) to use for execute the command on the remote machine, since there could be a different shell from localhost.

I think you will also need the `-t` param of `ssh` command:

> -t      Force pseudo-tty allocation.  This can be used to execute
>   arbitrary screen-based programs on a remote machine, which can be very
>   useful, e.g. when implementing menu services.  Multiple -t
>            options force tty allocation, even if ssh has no local tty.

Something as follow should get closer to what you are looking for:

```
ssh -it $KEY $USER@$HOST 'sudo su tom; echo $DATA >> /home/user/file.txt; bash'
```

Unfortunately, in the above solution the "concat" of `sudo su` && `echo` still doesn't work, but using `-c` parameter of `su` command should fix

> -c, --command=COMMAND        pass a single COMMAND to the shell with
>   -c

Comment: Yeah, those should be the correct flags to use in this situation!

Comment: `tee` has solved my issue, although it wouldv been nice to use the use instead of root.

   `ssh -i $KEY $USER@$HOST "echo "$DATA" |sudo tee /home/user/file.txt;"`

Comment: The `-t` flag still did not enable me to do that.

Comment: ok, thank you for the feedback, glad you solved

Answer (score 1):

Here is the command you specified:

```
ssh -i $KEY $USER@$HOST "sudo su tom; echo $DATA >> /home/user/file.txt
```

A couple minor notes about this:

- If `$KEY` or `$USER` or `$HOST` contain spaces, the command will produce unexpected behavior.  (Unlikely.)
- `$DATA` is expanded on the host you are running the `ssh` command on, not on the host you are logging into remotely.  (I'll assume this is what you intended.)
- You are missing a closing `"` at the end of your command.  I'll assume this is a copy-paste error.

Now the big point about this command, and the one that solves your problem:

**`sudo` isn't just for running commands as `root`.**  It is for, and I quote the man page:

```
sudo, sudoedit - execute a command as another user
```

So, **the simple command you want** is:

```
ssh -i $KEY $USER@$HOST "sudo -u tom echo $DATA >> /home/user/file.txt"
```

This assumes that `$USER` has permissions to write to `/home/user/file.txt`.  If it's only `tom` who has those permissions, then use:

```
ssh -i $KEY $USER@$HOST "sudo -u tom -i 'echo $DATA >> /home/user/file.txt'"
```

For more, read up on `man sudo`.